# "Other" requests skyrocket and stays whenever I add something to my Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Whenever I create a Cosmos DB resource from scratch in Azure, create a database with a new collection and one document, my number of requests shoot up to 20-30 per minute. The data insertion is done directly through the Data Explorer in the Azure portal.

Then it stays around here throughout the day and night (regardless if I'm using the DB or not), so there is always between 20-60 requests per minute, but **what are these reuqests**?

Where does the traffic come from and why am I being charged for these requests when I'm not even actively using the database except for storing one document in there?

Screencap from the monitoring in my Cosmos DB resource:

[image]

**Update**: Screencap from the requests activity from the last hour:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it would be impossible to guess why you have requests coming in. Also, the graph you're showing is only for a very brief amount of time (a few minutes maybe?).

Comment: @DavidMakogon There is no coding involved. I'm inserting data into a new document through the Data Explorer in the Azure portal. I added another graph showing the request activity from the last hour. I have not used the DB at all during this hour.

Comment: Were you able to understand what kind of requests are categorised in this Other requests? I am also having same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up switching over to Azure Table storage because of the limitations in Cosmos DB using the Document DB API.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a Cosmos DB in production that has no activity in the last 7 days, but 700RU/s in "Other" that I can't explain. This is costing hundreds of dollars per month to not do anything.